# How to find the type of an object array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a use case where An array is passed as an Object. I have to figure out at runtime the type of array and generate a list of the same type.

```
public class Test {

    public static Object getArray(Object value) {
        Object returnVal = value;
        if(value!=null && value.getClass().isArray()){
            returnVal = Arrays.asList(value).get(0);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] k = new int[]{1,2,3,4,43,4};
        Object val = getArray(k);
        // val should be 1st element of the array. So, val should be equal to 1.
    }
}
```

If I run the following code, I am getting a result as a List with the complete array as the 1st element.

I need to return only the first element of the array.

The value passed can be anything, so I cannot change the return type.

Comment: Why does the parameter need to be of type `Object`?

Comment: As I mentioned, the value passed can be of any type. I need to ignore them and only process if its an array

Comment: Why would you make a static method which can accept anything, but will only do something when the parameter is of a specific given type? Sounds like a design flaw to me.

Comment: @Synch This is a small runnable snippet I made for the purpose of the question. The original method is different and not static. I just shortened it to the point

Comment: Modified the question with required output

Comment: @Pardha.Saradhi I solved your problem see my answer.  A primitive array isn't an object array. For this reason `(Object[]) value`  the code doesn't work. Java  provides the `Array` class to solve get first element from all array types. Hope to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem:

```
import java.lang.reflect;

public static Object getArray(Object value){

    if (value != null && value.getClass().isArray()){
       return Array.getLength(value) == 0 ? null : Array.get(value, 0);
    }
    return value;
}
```

If you are sure that length of array can't be zero you can write the return statement like this:

```
return Array.get(value, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you cast the `value` to an `Object[]` array, `Arrays.asList(...)` will be invoked with a single element, the value itself.

However, your code does not reveal the same intention as your question: it looks like you're trying to return the object as such (if it's *not* an array) **or** the first element of the array (if `value` *is* an array). If so, you don't need a list at all. And you may use an `Optional` to give it a fluent new look (you can achieve the same without an `Optional`, of course):

```
return Optional.ofNullable(value)
        .filter(Object[]::isInstance)  // if value is an array
        .map(Object[].class::cast)     // cast to an Object[] array
        .filter(arr -> arr.length > 0) // ensure non-empty
        .map(arr -> arr[0])            // grab the first element
        .orElse(value);                // fallback to returning the raw value
```

The only awkward edge-case is an empty array, which will be returned as such.

Comment: Cannot cast Integer array to ObjectArray. Getting this. 
java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a List of a type known only at runtime.

You can find the type of the array using:

```
value.getClass().getComponentType()
```

but due to runtime type erasure, Lists don't have a type at runtime, so it doesn't matter whether you know the type of the array or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Object[] getArray(Object value) {
    return value != null && !value.getClass().isArray()
        ? new Object[] { value }
        : (Object[]) value;
}
```

If the object is not an array it wraps it in an array or else it casts it to an array.

You could make a type *checked* list, but unfortunately you somewhere need a `Class<T>` parameter for type safeness checking at compile time.

```
Object[] array = (Object[]) value;
List<?> list = Collections.checkedList(Arrays.asList(array), value.getComponentType());
```